# Robot Framework how to maximize windows application

Tags: windows, robotframework, maximize

I searched the web for a certain time but didn't find the important and necessary command of how to maximize a windows application using Robot Framework. What I have up to now is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           RPA.Desktop.Windows
Library           RPA.Desktop

*** Test Cases ***
Maximize
    ${app}=    Open using run dialog    calc.exe    Rechner
    RPA.Desktop.Press Keys    alt    space
    RPA.Desktop.Press Keys    x
    RPA.Desktop.Windows.Send Keys    {LWIN up}
    RPA.Desktop.Windows.Send Keys    {%SPACE x}
    Pause Execution
```

Nothing of this works. So how to maximize a normal application (not bowser using selenium) in windows?

Comment: calc.exe is special, a UWP app today with a very different .exe name.  Try it with notepad.exe

Comment: I tested this for a few days with calc.exe - unbelievable. Notepad directly works. Thank you. Do you also know how to send {LWIN up} with Send Keys to the application? "Send Keys    {LWIN up}" doesn't work even with notepad.exe.

Comment: Not possible, SendKeys was used back in the days that keyboards did not have a WIN key yet.  Intentionally not improved, it is never the right way to do automation.  In .NET (?) use System.Windows.Automation

Comment: Ok, thank you again! Difficult to mark now the right solution, since my solution was ok, but with the wrong application :-). If you like you can write your hint as an answer and I mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt space and x where ok, but calc.exe is problematic. Thank you Hans.